# Creating a pandas DataFrame from list of lists containing data from bs4 object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to create a DataFrame containing data scraped from a website. The data is placed into two lists - Job title and URL that links to the job application page. My aim is to then pass them into a list to create a DataFrame as demonstrated by https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-create-pandas-dataframe/

```
list_job_titles = []
list_job_URLs = []
for a in soup.find_all('a', href = re.compile("work-placement-internship")):
    URL_from_soup = (a['href'] + " ")
    title_from_soup =(a.text.strip())
    list_job_titles.append(title_from_soup)
    list_job_URLs.append(URL_from_soup)
    time.sleep(0.1)
data = [[list_job_titles],[list_job_URLs]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Job title', 'URL'])
```

I have tested the web scraping aspect of the script and it obtains all desired information from the site. However when it comes to creating the DataFrame I get the error:

> ValueError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns

I have then tried passing in one column header:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Job title'])
```

To which I get the output:

> Job Title
>
> 0  [Some job title...
>
> 1  [https://someURL...

Any idea how to split this into 2 columns, one for the title and one for the URL

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Replace:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Job title', 'URL'])
```

**With:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Job title": list_job_titles, "URL": list_job_URLs})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Job Title": list_job_titles, "Job URLs": list_job_urls})
```